# Are Jews & Christians Really Ahlul Kitab?

Tags: ahlul-kitab

I've been looking for clear-cut evidence of the claims that Jews and Christians are Ahlul Kitab mentioned in the Quran.

No where in the Quran does Allaah clearly mentions Jews and Christians as being Ahlul Kitab.

So, does anyone know where this idea of Jews and Christians being Ahlul Kitab come from?

Please provide clear-cute evidence and not ambiguous statements.
Keep in mind that Jews didn't exist when the Torah was revealed, and Christians didn't exist when the Injil was revealed.

I would like to discuss this further if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *People of the book* to mean the Christians in verse [4:171](http://quran.com/4/171):

   > O **People of the Scripture**, do not commit excess in your religion ... The Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, was but a messenger of Allah ... And do not say, "**Three**" ...

   Who say God is three and have Jesus in their religion? - the Christians.
2. *People of the book* to mean the Jews in verse [4:153](http://quran.com/4/153):

   > **The People of the Scripture** ask you to bring down to them a book from the heaven. But they had asked of Moses [even] greater than that....

   Who asked Moses of prophetic signs?- The Jews.

So, *The people of the book* collectively means *the Jews and the Christians*.

---

The idea of Jews and Christians being called as Ahlul Kitab probably has something to do with the fact that they themselves call their Holy Book *the Bible*, which means *the Book*.

Comment: The Christians are not the only ones who say Three and the Jews didn't exist during the time of Moses.

I think believing that ALL Jews and Christians are Ahlul Kitab is incorrect.  May be a group of them can be considered from Ahlul Kitab but not all of them.

Comment: @Sayyid i wrote: _Who say God is three and **have Jesus in their religion**?_ read again. And Who says Jews did not exist during the time of Moses? see [Jewish origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jews#Origins). Also, just like not All so called muslims are actually Muslims, all Jews or christians may not be Ahlul Kitab, but the term Ahlul Kitab is generally used to refer to mainstream Jews and Christians.

Comment: Well this answers pretty well, but to add pertaining to marriage, the only thing we're concerned about, dividing question into 2 parts,,, 1. [Allowed to marry people of the book(especially Christians) or not?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/allowed-to-marry-people-of-the-bookespecially-christians-or-not) and [Who is a Jew… According to Muslims?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/22991/11938) @Sayyid & MAKZ:

Answer (score 2):

Allah also mentions those who were given the Kitab 2:102, 2:121, 2:144-145, 3:19-3:23, 5:5, 9:29, 13:36, 74:31, 98:4, those who inherit the Kitab 35:32 and that this prophet (ie. Muhammad) was given the Kitab as well, 4:113, 5:48, 29:47.

From 2:109-113 it looks as though the Jews and Christians are from the Ahlul Kitab. Allah speaks of those among the Jews, Christians and Sabians who believe in Allah and the Last Day 2:62, 5:68-69. Would anyone believe in Allah and the Last Day without a kitab?