# Can Muslim men marry Jewish or Christian women?

Tags: quran, hadith, nikah, non-muslim

I read somewhere (I don't remember) that Muslims can marry Jews and Christians as they are Ahl-al-Kitab (People of Scripture).

Please let me know that if it is true for men as per Quran or Hadith.

this is not duplicate of that

Comment: Doesn't matter, even if it is duplicate or not, but you got your answer and have also accepted it.

Comment: Also a similar explanation could be found in this [answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/allowed-to-marry-people-of-the-book-or-not/23539#23539).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed. But the condition that the woman must be chaste has to be met. It is only allowed for the men.

> This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those who were given the Scripture is lawful for you and your food is lawful for them. And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among the believers and chaste women from among those who were given the Scripture before you, when you have given them their due compensation, desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse or taking [secret] lovers. And whoever denies the faith – his work has become worthless, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers. (Qur'an 5:5)

Comment: Some scholars, however, keep this ruling valid for only the Banu Israel and not all the Christians and Jews of modern times, and they argue that the Prophets of people whom we call Ahl al Kitab, were sent to a particular people/tribe, Bani Israel, and not the whole mankind. WaAllahuAlam