# Can a Muslim man marry a non Muslim woman in her country as per her local laws and customs?

Tags: nikah, non-muslim

I would like to ask if a Muslim man can marry a non-Muslim woman in her country, is it valid? Is it possible to have equal wedding ceremony, like if the woman is a Christian can a Muslim man marry the Christian woman to her church and will it be considered valid to Muslim?
Or if any case, the ceremony will be on a civil wedding in woman's country, is it valid still?

Comment: So why not ask directly *can a Muslim marry a Christian woman*? Also, look at the controversy, [Allowed to marry ' people of the book ' especially Christians or not?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/allowed-to-marry-people-of-the-book-especially-christians-or-not)

Answer (score 2):

Bismillah,

> I would like to ask if a Muslim man can marry a non Muslim woman in
> her country, is it valid?

Short answer is yes, it is valid. However, that non-Muslim woman must be chaste. Allah (SWT) says in Surat Al-Ma'idah ([verse #5](http://quran.com/5/5))

> This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those
> who were given the Scripture is lawful for you and your food is lawful
> for them. **And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among the
> believers and chaste women from among those who were given the
> Scripture before you**, when you have given them their due compensation,
> desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse or taking [secret]
> lovers. And whoever denies the faith - his work has become worthless,
> and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.

Regarding having the wedding ceremony in the church, the answer is **NO** because there will be some rituals and celebrations that are not part of Islam, some of them might actually be against the teachings of Islam.

Civil weddings are valid, but it's better if you also perform the wedding in your local mosque or any Islamic center before or after the civil wedding.

---

**References:**

- [IslamQA - English](https://islamqa.info/en/33656)
- [IslamWeb - Arabic](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/166583)

Answer (score 0):

Did you know many christian weddings involve drinking of wine? ( as the blood of christ ). Do you think that would be valid?

There is no "her country" or "my country". Islam is universal. A geographic location is not needed to practice Islam.

You can marry Christian women, provided they are chaste as Quran 5:5 says.
The definition of chaste is not as per western/Christian values but rather as per Islamic values.

The verse in 5:5 which permits to marry ahle-kitab also talks about giving her meher. Meher is part of Islamic law, simply implying It can only be valid if done in an Islamic way.

This will also set the tone of your marriage for your life. It messages that Islam is important to you.

Comment: Please consider elaborating your answer by adding references to support your claims.