# Love Marriage in Islam with non-muslim girl

Tags: love

Assalaamualaikum,My name is Washim I'm from Delhi (IN).
I would like to ask a question regarding marrying a non-muslim girl.
If marriage is necessary in Islam and what if I like a non- Muslim girl to marry? 
And what if I have the pure intention of taking her to the righteous path (Islam) before or after getting married to her.
Actually,I deeply loves her and I'd plan to help her in seeking knowledge of Islam and I believe if I'll tried so much (not forcefully) then one day she'll embrace Islam I can't decide the time it maybe a day before I die.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Muslim man marry a non-Muslim (and non-Ahl-al-Kitab) woman?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23497/can-a-muslim-man-marry-a-non-muslim-and-non-ahl-al-kitab-woman)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30058/can-a-muslim-man-marry-a-non-muslim-woman-in-her-country-is-it-valid?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can marry her, only if she accepts Islam and tells Shahadatain voluntarily. This is not a simple decision, but there are many examples of such convergence to Islam. Because if she really loves you, she will accept to research on your family, your thoughts, and your religion. Give here a change, and hope that she will accept the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Men are allowed to marry not muslim women. Marry her and hopefully one day you can convince her to convert. But make sure she understands that your religion is important to you and explain to her why.

Comment: Do you have evidences for your claim? Then please post then to support it. Men are allowed to marry beside muslim women only chaste women of the people of the book!

Comment: More of an accurate answer Men are allowed to marry Muslim women who are OF the book (Al-Kitab). This includes Jews and Christians.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas if you have an evidence for that feel free to post it. http://legacy.quran.com/5/5 makes it clear that only chaste Muslim women and chaste women among poeple of the book are halal for marriage

Comment: @Medi1Saif - interesting. Thank you. I was told and read (I believe...cannot remember) that as long as they are chaste AND of the book then it is permissible.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas of course the definition of chaste is a bit ambivalent. As i found for example a fatwa saying that a person who committed zina and afterwards sincerely repented is considered as chaste.