# How does a Muslim man go about marrying a Christian girl?

Tags: nikah, christianity

I want to marry a Christian girl without telling my parents because they would never agree.

What is the proper procedure of marrying a Christian girl?

I know that Muslims can marry Christians, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but figured I ought to say this any ways. It is important to know that according to the Christian's Bible, Christians are not to be unequally yoked. Meaning, a Christian should not marry someone who is not a Christian. So marrying her could be against her beliefs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed to marry ' people of the book ' especially Christians or not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/allowed-to-marry-people-of-the-book-especially-christians-or-not)

Comment: @Medi1Saif: This doesn't ask about it's permissibility, but about *how* to marry a Christian girl.  I don't think this is a duplicate.