# Relationship between man and woman without having any haram interactions before marraige

Tags: fiqh, relationships, reference-request

Is it haram to have a relation without having any haram interactions? If so then what a Muslim couple should do? It is difficult to marry as they are young but it is also difficult to stay away... and temporary marriage is also forbidden... I know that it is not allowed to touch,kiss,gaze or to meet alone... but if the just talk over the phone and share good things like hadith then what is the problem in doing so?

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning, Islam proposes us to not make a relationship before marriage. It says in the Qur'an, surah Al-Isra' 32: **Walaa taqrabu zina** - Do not approach zina. This ayat is the key to a lot of relationship problems. Does creating a *special relationship* between a boy and a girl is in the category? I'm not trying to be harsh but -  logically - I think it is. Especially because this relationship is the same kind with a 'more serious' - more dangerous relationship.

Zina is a crime - If you think the effects this can do, it's massive (It's sad a lot of people doesn't care). If it's not Allah who forbid this, no one can. Well, sexual activity is a need of everyone, and it's a double edged sword.

Now, I'm a Muslim teen myself. I know the desire of having contact with my crush -- *cough* *sorry* -- However, I still keep a 'safe distance' between us. It's a little difficult, I admit. Well, I did all that simply because once you're in a relationship, it's extremely difficult to not cross the line. You'll met more often, and you'll want to be private. Even if you can keep yourself not to cross the line, what if your partner does?

Well... I think that summarizes it. By the way, one thing you can do to hold it down is to fast... I don't do that very often but I try to do it sometimes :D

**Update**

This has been a very popular topic in the internet, so i think i might share some worth-to-read links:

http://caliph.wordpress.com/articles/boy-girl/
[Relationships according to Quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/relationships-according-to-quran) - It's from this site as well

I'm sure we know what's right and what's wrong. It's in our senses. It might be possible for one to have a relationship without private contacts - although i think this is impossible. If you want to keep going, then go to marriage :)

If you have another question, please comment!

Comment: we are in a  relation for 4 years....nothing happened between us....if we can continue like this will it still be haram?
And can you be specific about keeping the safe distance?does that mean not to contact with that person?

Comment: If you're serious about being with him/her - marrying him/her, doing it as soon as possible is the best way to avoid a risk. If you don't want to get that far - not that serious, then what's the point in that relationship? I mean, that might cause something troublesome in your future with another person, if it's going to be like that.

Comment: About my 'safe distance', it's just that i avoid too much contact. I talked, sometimes, just like a normal friend.

Comment: i am reading hadith about zina and searching things against relations before marraige.as far i came to know about touching,gazing,kissing-these things are not allowed.and having a sexual realtion is haram.but i haven't found anything about this matter- if i avoid touching,kissing and gazing..will it still be a sin?or it wont..can u give me any hadith or any ayat of Quran regarding this matter?

Comment: @user4646 Please see my update. If you're yet to be convinced, ask your parents - or search for an Imam to ask.