# Why cant I have female friends

Tags: friendship

I am a male and have been trying to find friends and was told I cant have female friends since I might fall into adultery. But then how can I have male friends I could fall into bad things with them too. I don't really see anything wrong with having female friends as long as I don't touch them or have lust for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Qur'an or Sunnah directly forbid male-female interactions aside from sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/does-the-quran-or-sunnah-directly-forbid-male-female-interactions-aside-from-se)

Comment: Female friends are forbidden to you rather than males because (presumably) you are attracted to females.